# Unable to play URL with Special character in MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, urlencode

I am trying to playing MediaPlayer with special-key character url but unable to play and getting an error code.  Although I played it with direct input Url too and still got an error.

```
 //// Input
String urlStr = "http://mydomain/php/playfile.php?src=7580&dst=7711&calldate=2014-04-09%2015:23:19&amaflags=3&duration=294&billsec=289&lastapp=Dial&mp3file=exten-7711-7580-20140409-152319-1397042599.3211.mp3"

URL localurl = new URL(urlStr);
            URI uri = new URI(localurl.getProtocol(), localurl.getUserInfo(),
                    localurl.getHost(), localurl.getPort(), localurl.getPath(),
                    localurl.getQuery(), localurl.getRef());
            localurl = uri.toURL();


            Log.d("localurl ", localurl.toString());
            Log.d("localurl.getQuery()", localurl.getQuery());

            String queryStr = localurl.getQuery();
            String pathStr = localurl.getPath();

            Log.d("localurl.getPath()", localurl.getPath());
            Log.d("uri.toASCIIString()", uri.toASCIIString());

            String encodeUrlStr = URLEncoder.encode(queryStr, "UTF-8");

            Log.d("encodeUrlStr", encodeUrlStr);


            String urlToplay = String.format("http://%s%s?%s", MasterView.mPreferences.getString("DomainName", ""),pathStr,encodeUrlStr);

            Log.d("url to play", urlToplay);



//// Output
http://mydomain/php/playfile.php?src%3D7580%26dst%3D7711%26calldate%3D2014-04-09%252015%3A23%3A19%26amaflags%3D3%26duration%3D294%26billsec%3D289%26lastapp%3DDial%26mp3file%3Dexten-7711-7580-20140409-152319-1397042599.3211.mp3
```

And On MediaPlayer to play audio stream url

```
 try {


                mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaplayer.reset();
                mediaplayer.setDataSource(urlToplay);
                mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                // mediaplayer.prepare();

                mediaplayer
                        .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mediaplayer.start();
                            }
                        });
                mediaplayer.prepareAsync();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.i("Exception", "Exception in streaming mediaplayer e = "
                        + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(16285): native_setup
V/MediaPlayer(16285): constructor
V/MediaPlayer(16285): setListener
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(16285): reset
V/MediaPlayer(16285): reset
V/MediaPlayer-JNI(16285): setAudioStreamType: 3
V/MediaPlayer(16285): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
V/MediaPlayer(16285): setVideoSurfaceTexture
V/MediaPlayer(16285): prepareAsync
V/MediaPlayer(16285): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-1004
E/MediaPlayer(16285): error (1, -1004)
V/MediaPlayer(16285): callback application
V/MediaPlayer(16285): back from callback
E/MediaPlayer(16285): Error (1,-1004)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a issue with the mediaplayer setup.
Here is how I would do it:

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MP3_URL);
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
});
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mediaPlayer.start();
            }
    });
```

Comment: I tried using onCompletion too but didnt worked and please tell me where can I get this data.get(position).getSONG_MP3() in my code

Comment: data.get(position).getSONG_MP3()= your song url - see updated code, in your case that will be urlStr

Comment: Sorry for late reply, actually I am unable to understood the usage of data ArrayList and get object as string and pass it to datasource source of MediaPlayer. I guess my main issue is with URL encoding.

Comment: I handled my mediaplayer by downloading the file and playing as it will never work with my URL as my url has cookie issue and cookie-flags needs to be passed in header to access the file, and I dont know how to pass cookie header onto the file. Alhough I have tried with other URL and it works fine with your code too.